# TN-Models-FP error "You should not pass `create` model without an `entity` model"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am [using](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@thinknimble/tn-models-fp) this TN-models-fp library to build a simple api based off the examples here is my api.ts

```
import { axios } from '../axios-instance'
import { createApi } from '@thinknimble/tn-models-fp'
import { todoShape } from './models'

const todoApi = createApi({
  baseUri: '/api/todos',
  client: axios,
  models: {
    entity: todoShape,
  },
})
```

Yet I am seeing an error

```
ype '{ entity: ZodObject<{ id: ZodNumber; title: ZodString; description: ZodString; completed: ZodBoolean; alertTime: ZodDate; createAlert: ZodBoolean; }, "strip", ZodTypeAny, { ...; }, { ...; }>; }' is not assignable to type '"You should not pass `create` model without an `entity` model"'.
```

here is my zod shape

```
import { z } from 'zod'

export const todoShape = z.object({
  id: z.number(),
  title: z.string(),
  description: z.string(),
  completed: z.boolean(),
  alertTime: z.date(),
  createAlert: z.boolean(),
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick fix is to remove the `z.object` from your shape.
Shapes are supposed to be plain objects with zod types as values of the keys.

In the docs we have a [couple of examples](https://github.com/thinknimble/tn-models-fp#quickstart) of shape definitions.

The error definitely is not the best in this case so good catch! We will improve this error in case the type of entity is not the expected one

Cheers!